# Azure logic app not executing after first run failed

Tags: azure, dynamics-crm, sharepoint-online, azure-logic-apps

This week an update to the azure logic apps was launched, which included a Dynamics CRM connector.

I'm trying to build a sample which will create an item in Dynics CRM after a list item has been created in a SharePoint List.

The logic app will run once. After it gives an error, it will not run again.

Do I need to do something before it will run again. Or can I force the logic app to be run on demand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Logic App that you have created will follow a default recurrence of 1 hour, unless it is instructed otherwise by the connector.

Note that a new run of the logic app will appear if and only if the trigger has fired. Just because you do not see any new runs does not mean that the trigger has stopped running.

You can inspect all runs of the triggers on the 'Trigger History' blade. This page gives a good overview on monitoring of logic apps:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-logic-monitor-your-logic-apps/

Answer (score 1):

I have not check out the logic apps update yet but before you could add a Recurrence Block to the logic app.

Then you could make it run ex. 1/hr OR run it manually by pressing the arrow "Select Trigger" - > "Run".

Answer (score 0):

depending on the app service plan you can change the recurrence frequency of the runs for your Logic App. 
Values vary from 1 (multiples of) Hour to 60 Second (multiples of second). so before you hit the save button, make sure you in the correct plan that allows this recurrence